# URL Rewriting - How to remove trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, url

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php?page=$1
```

I am using this code in my .htaccess for URL rewriting. The url changed to www.example.com/about/.

I want to remove the trailing slash from url.

Comment: If `/about/` is a real directory then trailing slash is added by `mod_dir` module.

Comment: You can try and use `DirectorySlash Off` at the top of your .htaccess however that could break some things. Like `DirectoryIndex` won't work and may result in a forbidden page